# Find arithmetic progression between two numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers, series

I have two numbers and I need to find an arithmetic progression between those two numbers in such a way it should always contain number **zero**.

Below is my code.

```
var numberOfPoints = 6;
var min = -5;   
var max = 10;
var step = (max - min) / numberOfPoints;
var pointsArray = [min];
var point = min;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
   point = point + step;
   pointsArray.push(+point.toFixed(2));
}
console.log(pointsArray); //[-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10]
```

Code works fine.

But if I change `min = -7`, I get the `[-7, -4.17, -1.33, 1.5, 4.33, 7.17, 10]` which is missing **zero**.

Following is the situation

1. `numberOfPoints` is fixed `min` and `max` varies.
2. `min` is always negative `max` may or may not be negative.
3. `A negative threshold value` can be added to `min` to get an arithmetic progression having number **zero** in it.

Comment: Isn't your second condition contradicting to requirement *always must include 0*? E.g. for  `min=-5` and `max=-1` there's no way zero is in.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov if  `min=-5`  `[-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10]` third element of array is zero.

Comment: @ozil ^^ but what if `max=-1` as well, since you said max can be negative...

Comment: @NickParsons A negative threshold value can be added to min to get an arithmetic progression having number zero in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is not solvable

```
Following is the situation

- numberOfPoints is fixed min and max varies.
- min is always negative max may or may not be negative.
- A negative threshold value can be added to min to get an arithmetic progression having number zero in it.
```

Prove: 
`numberOfPoints= 6`, `min=-1000` and `max=1`, you cant get `arithmetic progression` in 6 steps with zero, because in 6 steps minimum difference of step is `1001/6=166.86`, while if you include `0`, the maximum value of step must be `1` to not reach over the maximum.

Adding negative treshold does not matter as it only increase the value of step.

PS: I ignored this step in example above `min is always negative max may or may not be negative.`, because this step is even easier to prove that is not solvable. `min=-10`, `max=-9`, there is no zero between them and adding negative treshold does not change it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*

min and max must have opposite signs, because there's no zero between two negative numbers
but they cannot be arbitrary, they have to satisfy a condition

if the k-th term of the progression is zero then min + k * step = 0 or 
min + k * (max - min) / numberOfPoints = 0 
from which k = - numberOfPoints * min / (max - min)
the condition is that - numberOfPoints * min / (max - min) must be an integer 
in the interval [1, numberOfPoints]
otherwise there's no solution

in the first example that you have (-6) * (-5) / (10 - (-5)) = 3
but in the second (-6) * (-7) / (10 - (-7)) = 2.470588235294118
(-4, 2), (-3, 3), (-2, 4) will all work, but (-2, 3) won't

*/
```